# Condition number of the system $Ax = b$

Tags: linear-algebra

How much does a perturbation of b by $1\%$ change the solution $x$ of $Ax = b?$

Changing $b$ by $1%$ means multiplying it by $1.01$. If $Ax = b$, then $A(1.01x) = 1.01b$, by linearity. So a $1\%$ change of $b$, from $b$ to $1.01b$, causes a $1\%$ change in $x$, from $x$ to $1.01x$. Doesn't this mean that the condition number is always 1 for this system? Where's the mistake in my proof?

Comment: I'm guessing a perturbation of 1% means something more like $ \|b-\tilde{b} \| \approx 0.01$. Do you have a definition of a "perturbation of 1%"?

Comment: Yes, ‖−̃‖≈0.01, you're right!

Comment: In this case there are more choices for $\tilde{b}$ than just $1.01b$. For instance, if $b=[1,1]$ then $\tilde{b} = [1.01,.99]$ satisfies $\|b-\tilde{b}\| \leq 0.01$. So it is not enough to assume that the perturbation produces a scalar multiple of the original vector.

Comment: 1 norm of $b- \tilde {b}$ is $|1-1.01|+|1-0.99|=0.02$, so $\|b-\tilde{b}\|\leq0.02$, right?

Comment: I thought the norm was the 2 norm, but if it is the 1 norm you are correct (so you would need to adjust my example a bit).